# Typescript error : "audioPlayer.current may be null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typing

I'm trying to learn Typescript and for that I came back on some components to convert them into an errorless Typescript file.

I have here a bunch of errors that can't find the cause.I trying different options, but can't figure it out.

The first one is on refs. When I use theme with ref.current, I receive the error
"may be null"

Here is the component code :

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const AudioPlayer = () => {
  // state
  const [isPlaying, setIsPLaying] = useState(false);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [currentTrack, setCurrentTrack] = useState(null);

  // references
  let audioPlayer = useRef(null); //reference to our audioplayer
  let progressBar = useRef(); //reference to our progressBar
  let animationRef = useRef(); //reference the animation
```

The ref audioPlayer is declared here and used below to get the duration of the track

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const seconds = Math.floor(audioPlayer.current.duration);
    console.log(audioPlayer);
    setDuration(seconds);
    progressBar.current.max = seconds;
  }, [
    audioPlayer?.current?.onloadedmetadata,
    audioPlayer?.current?.readyState,
  ]);

  const togglePlayPause = () => {
    const prevValue = isPlaying;
    setIsPLaying(!prevValue);
    if (!prevValue) {
      audioPlayer.current.play();
      animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
    } else {
      audioPlayer.current.pause();
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationRef.current);
    }
  };

  const whilePlaying = () => {
    progressBar.current.value = audioPlayer.current.currentTime;
    setCurrentTime(progressBar.current.value);
    animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
  };

  const calculateTime = (secs) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    const returnedMinutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : `${minutes}`;
    const seconds = Math.floor(secs % 60);
    const returnedSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
    return `${returnedMinutes} : ${returnedSeconds}`;
  };

  const changeRange = () => {
    audioPlayer.current.currentTime = progressBar.current.value;
    setCurrentTime(progressBar.current.value);
  };

  const changeTrack = (e) => {
    setCurrentTrack(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    togglePlayPause();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative flex justify-center my-10 mx-4">
        <img src="/sphere_3D.jpg" alt="sph" width="600" />
        <p className="huit absolute">8</p>
        <input
          className="dots top-40"
          value="/piste1.mp3"
          onClick={(e) => changeTrack(e)}
        ></input>
        <input
          className="dots top-20 left-2/3"
          value="/piste2.mp3"
          onClick={(e) => changeTrack(e)}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <audio
          ref={audioPlayer}
          src={currentTrack}
          preload="metadata"
          onCanPlay={(e) => e.target.play()}
        ></audio>
        <button className="mx-5" onClick={togglePlayPause}>
          {isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}
        </button>

        {/* Current time */}
        <div>{calculateTime(currentTime)}</div>

        {/* progress bar */}
        <div>
          <input
            type="range"
            defaultValue="0"
            ref={progressBar}
            onChange={changeRange}
          />
        </div>

        {/* duration */}
        <div>{duration && !isNaN(duration) && calculateTime(duration)}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a type to the ref

```
const audioElem = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);
```

make sure you check for a null value before using current:

```
if (audioElem.current !== null) {
    audioElem.current.focus();
}
```